# Случайное число

Tags: c++

Значит, есть такая вот програмка: форма и на ней одно поле, в которое нужно ввести число , там, от 0 до 1000000. (число рандомно генерируется). Суть програмы в том, чтобы угадать число. Угадать число в промежуте [0, 1 000 000] очень сложно, так возникла идея чтобы написать програму, которая будет подставлять числа в ту форму и ждать пока число найдется =) Так вот вопрос: как это реализовать ?

Comment: Цикл for от 0 до 1000000 и проверять каждое число.

Comment: ну, так то оно очевидно =) но нужно написать свою програму, которая будет это всё проделавать с "чужой" программой !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужна программа, которая автоматически будет вводить данные в форму и нажимать отправить, имитируя работу пользователя. Если так, то рекомендую использовать системы автоматического тестирования графических интерфейсов. Как правило в таких системах используется собственный скриптовый язык или универсальный (Python, Tcl и др.).

Для вашей задачи рекомендую AutoIt - это свободно распространяемая программа и язык автоматизации типовых действий пользователя для ОС Windows. Работает и с браузерами.

[Подробное описание в Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt)

[Сайт программы](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Answer (score 0):

Расскажу, как можно угадать число. Это сделать несложно методом "обрезания".
Допустим, надо отгадать число в промежутке от 0 до 10. Я загадываю 8.
**Отгадываем:**

```
1) Берем число в середине промежутка. Это число 5.
2) Если число больше, то обрезаем левую часть( от 0 до 5 ), если меньше, соответственно.
3) Берем число в середине нового промежутка от 5 до 10. Это число 8. Так как середина - это 7.5. Округляем.
```

*Этот способ довольно известный, его часто используют, если не всегда*.

Comment: Только брать величину границы надо не 1 больше (или меньше, если левая часть). Обычно этот метод называют *двоичный поиск*.